# Overvoltage protection for Raspberry Pi with Zener Diode

Tags: power-supply, raspberry-pi, zener

I am aiming to power 2 Raspberry Pis via their GPIO pins. As there is no protection on GPIO, I would like to add one on my PCB (that will deliver the 5 V thanks to a TRACO, which can deliver 6 A maximum).

I looked on the internet how to do it, but I am a bit lost in the dimensioning part. I am following [this tutorial](https://www.rs-online.com/designspark/how-does-zener-diode-do-overvoltage-protection-in-circuit), and I don't know how to deal with point 2 in section 4 in my case:

> Calculate the load current that is linked across the circuit of overvoltage safety. This is 50mA for our example discussed above. Other than the load current, biasing current is required by Zener diodes. Therefore, the total current, plus the Zener diode biasing current, should be equal to the load current. For the above-mentioned example, it can be total current=50mA+10mA=60mA.

How can I know the load current of my RPi? Should I use the maximum (2*3 A)? Here is the diagram of what I planning to do.

[image: Power circuit with protection]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *power 2 Raspberry Pis via their GPIO pins* Why would you use the GPIO pins for powering the devices? The GPIO pins are not designed for that. I do hope you mean that you will be using the **GPIO connector** and power the devices via the VDD and VSS **pins** on that connector.

Comment: You should be adding a series resistor like you added R1, the current consumption of an RPi **varies a lot** so you'd need to use a low value resistor but then you'd need a very high power zener diode. You would do much better by **replacing R1 with a fuse** so that when the input voltage gets too high, the fuse will blow. Suffice to say that you should be using a good quality 5V power supply and then no protection is needed.

Comment: Sorry, yeah through misuse of language I called them GPIO. Yeah, I am planning to use the VDD and VSS of the GPIO connector, the +5 V and GND pins.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about a fuse instead of resistance! I read that TVS diode can absorb more power than Zener Diode, should I use that instead?
I don't know how the TRACO is good to avoid additional protection.

Comment: I'll check the TRACO datasheet

Comment: A TVS diode is more suitable for protecting against voltage spikes, not for protecting a 5 V circuit from getting 6 V. *I don't know how the TRACO is good* When in doubt, **don't use it** as it can **destroy** your RPis, yes even if you have protection in place. You need a supply with a **properly regulated** 5 V output. Even without a load the voltage needs to be below 5.5 V so **measure the voltage form the supply**. If it is not between 5.0 V and 5.3 V, I would not use it.

Comment: According to the TEN 40-1231 datasheet, the output range is between 4.950-5.250 V (with a load varying from 10 to 100 % of the rated max current), so should be ok in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it several years ago, using a Traco to power a Pi via the GPIO connector. There is no overvoltage protection, but I used a pair of power schottky diodes to protect against reverse polarity, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDbJV1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In fact this was a nicety, as with a PCB it's pretty hard to reverse power. If I did it again I'd probably use a MOSFET to protect against reverse. But anyway that design has been in use for several years and survived multiple power cycles without a single RPi failure. The Traco seems to be quite well behaved when used like this (which you would expect it to be, given its intended function).

Comment: One of my RPi will be powered directly from the PCB's track (and a full GPIO connector), so I guess I can avoid reversing current protection. For the second RPi, which is connected with only 2 cables, so I added MOSFET protection before the connector. With the TRACO you never used overvoltage protection then? So maybe I can avoid it, and just using a fuse.

Comment: no, as stated above, no overvoltage. If in doubt, load the Traco you intend to use, and check output with a storage scope. I maye well have done this but it is long ago. Obviously if you intend to use long cables where ringing might be an issue, it's different, and there you would want protection on the Pi itself, implying some kind of board mod, which isn't easy. In my case, there was only about 10cm of PCB track, and I had absolutely no issues.

Comment: In any case I'd avoid using a zener as they just aren't accurate enough and the V/I graph has too soft a knee for anything other than the crudest form of OV protection. Also speed might be an issue. You'd have difficulty blocking transients of say 5.7V without the zener drawing significant current at 5.5V.

Comment: @DarkPatate by the way, if this answers your question, please mark it as such.

Comment: In the case of a long cable, just the decoupling capacitor could be useful for the ringing, right? But in my case, the cable would be short (the PCB track as well).

Comment: Decoupling is always a good idea anyway. Yes it might well stop ringing also. I would definitely investigate a bit with a scope. I have a feeling that these Tracos are designed to power up with a gentle slow (ms) risetime, but I'm not sure. Also look at the datasheet?

Comment: for instance this datasheet says a typical risetime of 30ms. These devices are commonly used to directly power logic circuits, they wouldn't be suitable for that if they had big overshoot problems. https://www.tracopower.com/sites/default/files/products/datasheets/tmr6wi_datasheet.pdf